# Pipe in C - scanf seems to be not working when reading from pipe

Tags: c, fork, pipe, scanf

I have written the following program to understand how pipes work in C. But it is not producing the expected output. I have used pipe to connect the parent process's stdout to child process's stdin. I have used printf and scanf for this purpose. But the child program seems to wait for input instead of reading it using scanf. 
The code follows the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int pipefd[2];  
    pipe(pipefd);   
    int pid = fork();   // --- fork here ---    

    if (pid == 0){  // child process
        printf("child process\n");  

        int a=0, b=0;   

        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0],0);
        close(pipefd[0]);

        scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
        printf("%d%d", a, b);
        exit(0);    
    }

    else{   // parent process
        printf("parent process\n");

        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1],1);
        close(pipefd[1]);

        printf("%d%d", 1, 2);

        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output :
parent process
child process
12

Actual output :
parent process
child process

Comment: Did you try adding a newline when printing from the parent?

Comment: add `fflush(stdout);` after printf in the parent and nondigit characters into the printf after each number. Well now I see your ` scanf("%d%d",...)` which also will create problem. You can not have two consecutive numbers without separator. It would be scanned as a single big number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush stdout for it the buffer to be send over the pipe. You can do that by adding `fflush(stdout)`:

```
printf("%d%d", 1, 2);
fflush(stdout);
```

Then you also need to add some whitespace (doesn't matter which one) to the end of the output, because `scanf` will wait for a whitespace or EOF:

```
printf("%d%d ", 1, 2);
fflush(stdout);
```

Another way to flush the output and add the whitespace in one go might be adding a newline to the output:

```
printf("%d%d\n", 1, 2);
```

While this seems to work, I am not entirely sure this is guaranteed to flush the pipe.

However this will still not work as expected, because the printed output is `12`, which is interpreted by `scanf` as **one** integer and `scanf` will again wait infinitely for the second integer. So add a delimiter whitespace:

```
printf("%d %d ", 1, 2);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: If I write printf("parent process") instead of prinf("parent process\n"), the message is not printed onto the terminal screen. But if I write printf("child process") instead of printf("child process\n"), the message is still printed onto the terminal. So why is it that sometimes stdout gets flushed even without writing "\n"?

Comment: @nnori In the case of `printf("child process")` the process ends afterwards at `exit(0)`. At that point every stream is flushed and closed, so you see it printed. In the case of `printf("parent process")`, since you do not flush before redirecting, the full buffer containing `parent process1 2 ` is sent to the child process instead of being printed to the terminal.